# Start onTouchEvent After onClick Event

Tags: java, android, imagebutton, touch-event

I am trying to set the image button (pushClick) in my Activity to enable onTouchEvents used to rotate a needle graphic.  Unfortunately, the onTouchEvent is active regardless of if I click on the image button or not.  How can I prevent the onTouchEvent from firing until after the image button is clicked?

```
public void pushClick(View pushClick) {
    switch (pushClick.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn_push:

        make(degrees);

    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        startRotating();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        stopRotating();
        break;
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

private void startRotating() {
    returnRotating = false;

    if (!keepRotating) {
        keepRotating = true;

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (keepRotating) {
                    degrees = (degrees + 1) % 360;
                    make(degrees);

                    handler.postDelayed(this, INTERVAL);
                }
            }
        }, INTERVAL);
    }
}

private void stopRotating() {
    keepRotating = false;

    if (!returnRotating) {
        returnRotating = true;

        final Handler handler = new Handler();

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (returnRotating) {
                    degrees = (degrees - 1) % 360;
                    make(degrees);

                    handler.postDelayed(this, INTERVAL);
                }
            }
        }, INTERVAL);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd bet that there's a better way to do this, but here off the top of my head:

```
private boolean buttonClicked = false;

public void pushClick(View pushClick) {
    switch (pushClick.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn_push:
        buttonClicked = true;
        make(degrees);

    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if(buttonClicked)
    {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            startRotating();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            stopRotating();
            break;
        }
    } 

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: This actually worked like a charm!  I was trying to figure out how to add an if() to the onTouchEvent using an int, but was having a lot of syntax issues.  Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

You could also add the OnTouchListener (from whatever view you want it attached to) when your image button is pressed, and remove it when it's clicked again (if that's what you want).

Comment: I did try moving the onTouchListener into the image button section as a boolean but ran into force closes so I backed it out in favor of an easier approach.